# Google Chrome: maximum of 4 chrome.commands allowed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have run into what I think is a hard maximum of 4 chrome.commands allowed, based on the following error I get in Google Chrome when trying to add 5 or more in the manifest.json file:

`"Could not load extension from '[Extension Path]'. Too many commands specified for 'commands': The maximum is 4."`

Is there any particular reason for this limit, or any way to get around it?

For context: I'm currently working on an extension that adds the current page as a bookmark to a specific folder based on a specific hotkey, currently along the lines of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, up to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: I think you can move your logic into a popup. A single command will be used to open the popup, and there you can use shortcuts for a user to select a specific folder. This approach will also provide the benefit of error checking, because the popup can list foldernames for reference. And it allows you to extend number of the folders and "commands" to an arbitrary value, not limited to 10 (0 - 9). I don't think it introduces significant inconvenience by the necessity to press keys separately (common command first, and internal shortcut next (can be a single key)).

Comment: @Stan: Since it's looking like the limit is indeed an immutable one, this is sounding like the nicest alternative. I've actually already got a popup responding to a hotkey (via the usual default popup method, that is, though I may go with something more like a keyword launcher), so it would make a lot of sense to do it in this manner once that's up. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have looked at source code and figured out following lines of code.

constant declared for error message in **extension_manifest_constants.cc**

```
const char kInvalidKeyBindingTooMany[] =
    "Too many commands specified for 'commands': The maximum is *.";
```

constant declared for maximum number of commands in **extension.cc**

```
// The maximum number of commands (including page action/browser actions) an
// extension can have.
const size_t kMaxCommandsPerExtension = 4;
```

and validation code in **extension.cc** looks for following check

```
if (commands - > size() > kMaxCommandsPerExtension) { 
      * error = ErrorUtils::FormatErrorMessageUTF16(
        errors::kInvalidKeyBindingTooMany,
        base::IntToString(kMaxCommandsPerExtension));
        return false;
}
```

Google developers marked constant to 4, so you can not add more than 4 commands for now.

### Work Around:

Star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167419) and look for developers response, if you really want to go with commands, you have to create multiple extensions with commands set of 4 for each.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hello, you said: `if you really want to go with commands` does that mean there are other ways to make shortcuts on Chrome? What are they?

Answer (score 12):

This is a very old question but I had a hard time finding information anywhere and this question was the top google search result for a few of my searches, so I'll add some info here.

Despite the wordage of the error, you can have **as many commands as you want**. This error actually refers to the number of "suggested_key" objects you can have. [Chrome's documents](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands) specify the following:

> An extension can have many commands but only 4 suggested keys can be specified.

So in your manifest, while you can specify additional commands, you can only give 4 of them the "suggested_key" object

```
"commands": {
    "contains-suggested-key": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo"
      },
      "NO-suggested-key": {
          "description": "user must specify shortcut keys for this from the extensions page"
      }
}
```

Comment: Any idea if the limit of 4 suggested shortcuts includes the `_execute_browser_action` command? Since it's part of the `commands` object in the manifest, which is mentioned in the error message, I'm guessing yes. My extension currently has 4 suggested shortcuts (including one for `_execute_browser_action`), and I'm planning on adding some more commands. Guessing those won't be able to have default shortcuts.