# Key binding on a flash page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know if the following is possible - I'm having trouble finding information regarding my question on the web. I was looking into creating a Google Chrome extension to work with a webpage, until I realized that the page was in fact built with flash. Originally I wanted to bind an onClick event for an input on the webpage to display a form (which would be through the extension I'm building).

However, because the page is build in flash I no longer believe that this will be a possibility. So, my next idea was to bind the form's loading to a certain combination of keys (ctrl + d) for example, that the user would click.

For example:

The user is using the flash form with my extension running in the background. The user focuses on an input (text box let's say) and proceeds to click the keys (Ctrl + D). Upon clicking these keys, my extension pops open a web-form. The user types in what he wants in the form and then clicks "Save" - A submit button on my web-form. When the user clicks 'save', the data from the web-form is stored in the clipboard and the form closes. Finally, the focused input is filled in with the data from the clipboard.

Two questions:

1. Do Google Chrome extensions support key binding like this?
2. Will I be able to copy input from my generated form (through the extension) and paste it back into the input field on the flash page?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Do Google Chrome extensions support key binding like this?

Yes, you can specify custom key board shortcuts catered to platform using [chrome.commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html).

You can directly trigger `browser action\page action` popup page or do any customized functionality by defining a key.

### Sample Code of manifest

```
{
    "sample": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+S",
            "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+P"
        },
        "description": "Thisismycustomkeyforchromeextension"
    },
    "_execute_browser_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
            "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
            "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
        }
    }
}
```

However, `maximum of 4 keys` are supported so far! For further information refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000217/google-chrome-maximum-of-4-chrome-commands-allowed/14000881#14000881)

#### 2. Will I be able to copy input from my generated form (through the extension) and paste it back into the input field on the flash page?

Yes, with combination of [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) it is possible.

## References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)
- [Commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html)