# Enable default keyboard shortcut for a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to set a default keyboard shortcut for an extension by default?

What changes are required in manifest.json to have that default keyboard shortcut set by default when a given extension is installed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands API allows you to define specific commands<sup>**1**</sup>, and bind them to a default key combination<sup>**2**</sup>. Each command your extension accepts must be listed in the manifest as an attribute of the 'commands' manifest key.

<sup>**1**</sup>: Commands Format

```
Properties of Command

    name ( optional string )
        The name of the Extension Command EX: 'execute_browser_action' or '_execute_page_action' or some other custom name
    description ( optional string )
        The Extension Command description 
    shortcut ( optional string )
        The shortcut active for this command, or blank if not active.
```

<sup>**2**</sup>:Combinations Possible

Combinations that involve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> are not permitted in order to avoid conflicts with the AltGr key. Also note that on Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is automatically converted to <kbd>Command</kbd>. If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead, please specify <kbd>MacCtrl</kbd>

## SO Reference for Additional Information:

[Google Chrome: maximum of 4 chrome.commands allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000217/google-chrome-maximum-of-4-chrome-commands-allowed/14000881#14000881)

## Reference:

- [**Chrome.Commands API**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html)
- [Chrome.commands API Bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167419)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you assign a default, that means that users who install the extension can never ***unset*** that shortcut. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).